# Android Activity specific to particular flavor to be configured in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-productflavors, appodeal

**Context**

I have two product flavors free and paid. In free I use advertising and for paid there is no advertising.

I want to use a 3rd party module in my free version of the app, in my particular case AppoDeal for advertising. The integration doc mandates me to add a whole set of `<activity>`, `<meta-data>` and other tags that are a subset of `<application>` tag.

I don't want to polute the base `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Is it possible? Is it possible to add this in `AndroidManifest.xml` file located in `free` directory, recreating/duplicating the `<application>` tag? Or is there a better way?

Your advice based on your experience is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not a very good variant, because frameworks usually merge all manifests during build. btw, what's your framework? take a look at this, might be helpful https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html another simple way is just to contact their support, they respond quickly